# Express gateway cannot GET

Tags: node.js, express, api-gateway

I am trying to setup multiple (nodejs) services in express gateway, but, for some reason, the second service is not picked up. Please find below my gateway.config.yml

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  config:
    host: localhost
  actions:
    host: localhost
serviceEndpoints:
  configService:
    url: "http://localhost:3002"
  actionService:
    url: "http://localhost:3006"
policies:
- basic-auth
- cors
- expression
- key-auth
- log
- oauth2
- proxy
- rate-limit
pipelines:
  - name: basic
    apiEndpoints:
    - config
    policies:
    - proxy:
      - action:
          serviceEndpoint: configService
          changeOrigin: true
  - name: basic2
    apiEndpoints:
    - actions
    policies:
    - proxy:
      - action:
          serviceEndpoint: actionService
          changeOrigin: true
```

Answer (score 1):

That is expected, because apiEndpoints config part uses the same host and path to build routing

```
apiEndpoints:
  config:
    host: localhost
  actions:
    host: localhost
```

what you can do is to somehow separate it by path

```
apiEndpoints:
  config:
    path: /configs
  actions:
    path: /actions
```

in that way `localhost/configs/db` will go to config service `..:3002/configs/db` 
and `localhost/actions/magic` will go to actions `..:3006/actions/magic`

you may also want to install Rewrite plugin 
https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/rewrite/

in case target services have different URL patterns

Comment: This helped me. However, what if you want to specify an array of paths?

Comment: What address ports do you see in browser? 3002 and 3006? Or just 8080?